# Why getting a text selection from textarea works when a button clicked but not when a "div" clicked (in Internet Explorer)

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, textarea, textselection

Consider the following code: ([Live demo here - Open in Internet Explorer 7 or 9](http://jsfiddle.net/RbSLw/5/))

HTML:

```
<textarea>Hello Stack Overflow</textarea>
<input class="a" type="button" value="Click here does the job" />
<div class="a">But clicking here not :(</div>
```

JS:

```
    function getInputSelection(el) {
    var start = 0, end = 0, normalizedValue, range, textInputRange, len, endRange;

    if (typeof el.selectionStart == "number" && typeof el.selectionEnd == "number") {
        start = el.selectionStart;
        end = el.selectionEnd;
    } else {
        range = document.selection.createRange();

        if (range && range.parentElement() == el) {
            len = el.value.length;
            normalizedValue = el.value.replace(/\r\n/g, "\n");

            // Create a working TextRange that lives only in the input
            textInputRange = el.createTextRange();
            textInputRange.moveToBookmark(range.getBookmark());

            // Check if the start and end of the selection are at the very end
            // of the input, since moveStart/moveEnd doesn't return what we want
            // in those cases
            endRange = el.createTextRange();
            endRange.collapse(false);

            if (textInputRange.compareEndPoints("StartToEnd", endRange) > -1) {
                start = end = len;
            } else {
                start = -textInputRange.moveStart("character", -len);
                start += normalizedValue.slice(0, start).split("\n").length - 1;

                if (textInputRange.compareEndPoints("EndToEnd", endRange) > -1) {
                    end = len;
                } else {
                    end = -textInputRange.moveEnd("character", -len);
                    end += normalizedValue.slice(0, end).split("\n").length - 1;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return {start: start, end: end};
}


function getselection() {
  var selectedText = getInputSelection($("textarea")[0]);
  var start = selectedText.start;
  var end = selectedText.end;
  alert("Start: " + start + ", End: " + end);
}

$(".a").click(getselection);
```

The `getInputSelection()` function is taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7186586#answer-7188053).

For some reason, when the `<div>` is clicked, the result is always:

```
Start: 0, End: 0
```

Any ideas how to fix that ?

Comment: Using jsfiddle it seems both of them don't really work: http://jsfiddle.net/nayish/cKt8e/

Comment: You have to select some text (or move the cursor) in the textarea, and then to click the element.

Comment: In that case it works fine by me, what browser are you running this on? I'm running it on chrome.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that clicking the `<div>` loses the focus on the textarea before the `getInputSelection()` function executes. There are two alternatives:

- Either use the `mousedown` event instead: http://jsfiddle.net/RbSLw/13/, or
- Make the `<div>` unselectable (done by adding a `unselectable="on"` attribute in IE): http://jsfiddle.net/RbSLw/14/.

Comment: @Misha: One caveat with `unselectable`: it only applies to that element and not to child elements. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/826782/css-rule-to-disable-text-selection-highlighting/4358620#4358620

Comment: thanks, your answer helped a lot. thanks. I have no idea where you got this knowledge from)

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is caused by explorer. When you click on a button the focus is not lost from the input field but when you click on the `div` it removed and hence the selected text is no longer selected.

What you want to do is find a way to overcome this by forcing clicking on a div to not remove the focus from the `input`.

You may be better off simply saving the start and end values everytime they change and this way when you click them it won't matter if it is selected or not.

Hope this helped :)