# How to get selected text from a text area in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

If i select a text from a text area i need to know which text is selected, for example "hello world" if i select hello i would like to see hello is selected how can i do this in jquery. and i want to make it bold.

```
<textarea id="editor" cols="80" rows="20">
   Hello world, This is Me!
</textarea> 
<button onclick="SelectText()">
  Bold
</button>
```

Comment: found this perhaps it will help

[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7186586/how-to-get-the-selected-text-in-textarea-using-jquery-in-internet-explorer-7]

Comment: Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5379120/jquery-get-the-highlighted-text

Comment: duplicate of many posts.

Comment: `i want to make it bold`. You can't apply styles in textarea content.

Answer (score 0):

About to make the selected content as bold, you can't do that directly in the textarea but you can do that using editable divs. This plugin could help you: http://mistic100.github.io/jquery-highlighttextarea/

About your comment: "How can i get the all text from a div excluding html tags?" you can use something like this: jQuery('.yourDiv').text();