# How to wrap a html tag around a text selected in an input?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, input

The problem is:
I have an input text type element, and a button beside it.

Once the button is clicked, the selected text inside the input must wrap with a html element. For example, when the button is clicked, the selected text wrapped with `<span style='color:red'></span>` !

Does anyone has any solution ?

Comment: What have  you tried?

Comment: Not 100% sure what you mean by "wrap with a html element".  Can you give an example of before and after?

Comment: Sorry guys , i had written a html tag in the question that, which didn't show. i edited now, so any misunderstanding of question may clear now !

Comment: Cuz learn to format the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @RémyJ wrote, you can use jQuery `select` event, to get the selection. Try this:

```
var start, end;
$('#tf').select(function(e) {
    start = e.target.selectionStart;
    end = e.target.selectionEnd;
});

$('.wrap').click(function() {
    var val = $('#tf').val();
    var newVal = val.substr(0, start) + '!' + val.substr(start, (end-start)) + '!' + val.substr(end);
    $('#tf').val(newVal);
});
```

HTML:

```
<input type="text" id="tf"> 
<button type="button" class="wrap">wrap</button>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/qh95xyeq/

Answer (score 0):

A similar question has been asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16036745/how-to-get-selected-text-from-a-text-area-in-jquery). 
You could use the JQuery select method ([here](https://api.jquery.com/select/)) or the JS selection method ([here](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/API/Selection)). And then replace selection with HTML wrapped block.