# In JavaScript how to copy Range to another Node

Tags: javascript, css, selection

I have a textarea in my application and a DIV which contains the text of that textarea plus some SPANS for highlighting. I'd like to be able to select some text in the textarea, click a button, and have that button highlight that exact text only in the DIV.

I've been trying to accomplish this by creating a new range and using the startOffset and endOffset properties of the textarea selection, but I can't quite get it to work. Is this possible and if so how would you go about it?

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16036745/how-to-get-selected-text-from-a-text-area-in-jquery

Comment: @PierreEmmanuelLallemant I don't think that will work for my use case because that would just grab the text. The same text may be repeated several times for example.