# Textarea Selected Text Drag and Drop Copy

Tags: javascript, html

I want the users of my application to be able to highlight text from a `textarea` and drag and drop it into a text `input`.

I want to change the default behavior (the user shouldn't have to hold down <kbd>CTRL</kbd> or <kbd>ALT</kbd>) to copy the text rather than being moved from the textarea to the input.

I've already tried using jQuery `Draggable` and `Droppable`. I could see how this would work if a `div` or a static static would be selected and a helper clone was used, but I don't know how to do it with a random text selection in a `textarea`.

Comment: Isn't this a functionality of the browser / operating system and nothing to do with the browser / code?

Comment: You say that you tried using Draggable and Droppable, but can you explain what exactly you tried? AFAIK Draggable and Droppable are for entire html elements, and wouldn't be the correct approach for highlighted text in a textarea element. What else have you tried so far?

Comment: Have a look at this tutorial: http://www.htmlgoodies.com/html5/tutorials/html-5-drag-drop-basics.html#fbid=UOMuIcaZ6iu

Comment: There is an example of how to get the selected text in a textarea in this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7186586/how-to-get-the-selected-text-in-textarea-using-jquery-in-internet-explorer-7 and the other answer there points to a jquery plugin that works for IE7, IE8, IE9, FF, Chrome that may help your cause.

Comment: I should have said that I already have the selected text from the textarea stored in a string, it's just the drag and drop/copy functionality that I'm having trouble with since the text itself is not an html element.

Answer (score 1):

You could try the following hack:

1. On select create a transparent `div` and copy the selected text into it, with something like 'window.getSelection'
2. Make the div Draggable and Droppable
3. On drop get the content from the `div`, populate the `input` field and clear the div